# Can't Compare JSON Array with JavaScript Array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Ok so I have a JSON object that I send to the test() function as a parameter. See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#getdata').click(function(){


    $.ajax({                                      
    url: '<?php echo base_url().'jqueryDB/jquery';?>',                  //the script to call to get data    
    type:'POST',      
    data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php for example "id=5&parent=6"
    dataType: 'json',                //data format      
    success: function(output_string){
                    $("#result_table").append(output_string);
                    test(output_string);
    }
  });

}); 
</script>
```

My test function looks like this: (**Commented section explains more**)

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    window.output = [];  // global array
    function test(arg){
    output = arg;

    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <td></td>
                <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
                <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>

      // This is where I am having problems. I specify index zero for output and sooner or
     // later file.name should match, but it never does and I'm not sure why??
    // So then I do else if ( "5.jpg" == file.name ) and it does work....As you can
   // see that I test it in the line right below the else if, and it displays the same as file.name.

            {% } else if ( output[0].localeCompare( file.name ) ) { %}
                    <td class="name">{%=String(output[0])%}{%=String(file.name)%}</td>
                    <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
                    {% } %}</td>
                    <td class="name">
                        <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                {% } %}
                    <td class="delete">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
                        </button>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
                    </td>
        </tr>
        }
    {% } %}
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong in my comparison? When I do`else if ( output[0].localeCompare( "5.jpg" ) ) { %}` it doesn't work as well. So even though the output on my screen when I test it shows 5.jpg, the JSON object is not allowing me to compare it to other things other than itself. I did compare it to itself and of course it worked ;).

Comment: json **IS** javascript. it's just a textual representation of a javascript data structure, e.g. pretty much exactly what you'd have on the right-hand-side of an assignment operation, `var x = ...jsonishere...`. If you're talking about a json **STRING**, then simply use a json parser to convert it back to a native JS data structure.

Comment: JSON is not javascript, it's technically not even a subset of javascript.

Comment: @Esailija You're so wrong here. It's *exactly a subset of object literal notation in JavaScript*.

Comment: @esailija: "(J)ava(S)cript (O)bject (N)otation" ring a bell?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no it's not even a subset of the object literal notation http://jsfiddle.net/kbThH/1/

Comment: So I have a JSON array, how would I go about using the json parser to convert it back to a native JS array?

Comment: @Esailija Wow. that Example right there shows your thorough lack of understanding on this subject.

Comment: @Esailija: before you dig yourself any deeper, look at the specification's official homepage: http://json.org/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy so tell me why is that example somehow invalid then? Is shows that what is valid JSON is not valid javascript object literal. That should be enough for anyone to conclude that it's not a subset.

Comment: What are you guys talking about? I have this running and you see that example below the else if statement. It works and the outputs[0] has a value of 5.jpg that gets printed to the screen...so if I can do that why can I not compare it with other arrays, strings, etc?

Comment: @Esailija can you illustrate by example a snippet of JSON that would either be a syntax error in JavaScript or semantically inconsistent?

Comment: @Esailija ah OK I see the fiddle - your fiddle is set up incorrectly. The embedded Unicode escape is evaluated by JavaScript in the initialization of the string constant. If you double the backslash, then it works fine.

Comment: @Pointy no it's correct. I meant for the JSON parser to see a literal 2028. This is the whole point where the grammar differs.. javascript doesn't allow line terminators in strings (10, 13, 2028 and 2029) where as JSON allows anything in strings as long as it's not a control character, \, or ". This means, in a JSON string, 2028 is valid. But in javascript string it's not. That's why eval fails and JSON.parse doesn't. If you use second backslash, then you are literally parsing \u2028, not the literal 2028 character.

Comment: @Pointy also see http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset/ for more complete explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different statements:

```
if ("5.jpg" == file.name)

if ("5.jpg".localeCompare(file.name))
```

If the two strings are the same, the first comparison will return `true` and the body of the `if` statement will be run.  [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) will return zero if the two strings are the same which is, in the context of `if` statements, the same as `false`.  You likely want

```
{% } else if (output[0].localeCompare(file.name) == 0) { %}
```